# How to get parent child relationship in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have multiple executable files running in the server in different ways either from the task scheduler or from the controller, which is not appropriate now i have to change this using python

I need to write a python script which can initiate the executables as a separate process which holds the parent process ID to form a parent-child relationship, to do this i have used multiprocessing and subprocess

```py
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def Do_Something():
    exe_str = r"C:/Users/De/desktop/CreateFileWithCurrentDate.exe" 
    C_Pro = subprocess.Popen(exe_str, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) 
    print(C_Pro.pid)

# To get list of all the process running 
processes = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):   # Looping through to create multiple process based on the range with parent child Process
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Do_Something)  # Mechanism to create multiple process 
        p.start()  #Start the process async 
        processes.append(p) #Adding all the created process to the list 
        print(f'Parent Process ID: {p._parent_pid}, New Child Process ID: {p.pid}')
```

Here i am able to create multiple processes using the multiprocessing module, like a single parent and multiple children, but the actual problem is when i am triggering the method Do_Something as a process inside which i am using subprocess module which is again creating another process, this shouldn't be the case as the executable should be the child process ID which is created using multiprocessing module

Please help me out in this to archive multiprocessing using parent and child relationship

thanks

Comment: Sorry but I find your question unclear. Could you check your English? Also, what is `Initiate_Crawler`, and where is `Do_Something` used?

Comment: @alec_djinn i have removed Initiate_Crawler and replaced with Do_Something and the question is i need to run multiple exe's as a process each and each process id should have a parent process id so that i can controll all the processes using parent process id

Comment: What is the expected outcome? What does it means `which holds the parent process ID` holds where? in a variable? Who is the Parent in your case?

Comment: @alec_djinn the expected output is one parent process ID and multiple child process IDs where the child process ids are related to the executable files